# Issue when limiting on DATE9. pulled from HIVE within PROC SQL statement

Tags: sql, hive, sas

I am trying to pull some data from HIVE and I am having issues when comparing against a date that is in DATE9. format. I created a macro variable containing a date9 which is 30 days prior to todays date. When comparing that to the HIVE date it is returning zero records but I know they are there.

This is how I created my date9 variable.

```
data _null_;                            
call symputx( 'START_DATE', put(Today()-30,date9.));
run;
```

This is my query I use it in. I had to put the date between quotes because otherwise it thought it was a column.

```
PROC SQL;
   CONNECT TO HADOOP (SCHEMA=HIVE_DATA  DBMAX_TEXT=255);
   CREATE TABLE DATA AS SELECT * FROM CONNECTION TO HADOOP ( 
   SELECT DISTINCT AA.*
         FROM HIVE_TABLE AS AA
    LEFT JOIN HIVE_TABLE_2 AS BB
           ON AA.KEY=BB.KEY
        WHERE AND AA.HIVE_DATE >= '&START_DATE.')
   ;
   DISCONNECT FROM HADOOP;
   QUIT;
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: why using a variable at all for this?

Comment: What would be your suggestion? This is going to be a daily automated process.

Comment: so you run the create a table once a day with data from the last 30 days?

Comment: also in the sql `date_sub(current_date, 30)`

Comment: Is "WHERE AND" some special HIVE keyword? How is it different than "WHERE"? How does HIVE represent dates?  Does it really use the style that the DATE9. format creates?  You cannot resolve macro code inside of single quotes: try `%bquote('&start_date')` instead to get the single quotes around the macro variable's value.  Or add them when you create the macro variable.

Comment: You might want to setup the pass-through date literal using format `yymmdd10.` instead of `date9.`

Comment: @nbk  You were correct! date_sub(current_date,30) worked!